# Not able to set the row order in seaborn.relplot

Tags: python-3.x, seaborn

i am new to python and seaborn, i am using the dataset from [kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/jessemostipak/hotel-booking-demand), now i want to visualize the data, this is my code

```
def add_if_zero(x):
    if (x['stays_in_weekend_nights']+x['stays_in_week_nights'])==0:
        return 1
    else:
        return (x['stays_in_weekend_nights']+x['stays_in_week_nights'])

_data['total_days_of_stay']=_data.apply(lambda x:add_if_zero(x),axis=1)
x_order=['January','February','March','April','May','May','May','August','September','October','November','December']

sns.relplot(x='arrival_date_month',
            y='total_days_of_stay',hue='hotel',
            kind='line',data=_data,height=10,aspect=.9,row_order=x_order)
```

i am getting the plot and i want the order to be from jan-dec but i am getting a random variable in the x-axis

i tried passing the order to the row_order attribute in array as well as in string format but nothing seems to work

**as per the documentation**

> row_order, col_orderlists of strings, optional Order to organize the
>   rows and/or columns of the grid in, otherwise the orders are inferred
>   from the data objects.

**UPDATE 1:**

[image]

Comment: You pass a single string to `x_order`, but as the documentation states, it needs to be a list of strings.

Comment: well, i tried the list pf string as well but it doesnt work

Comment: In that case check  [mcve]

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, i have attached the screenshot, hope this will help

Comment: Oh I see. row_order determines the order of subplot content. Here you only have one subplot. If you want to treat your x axis as categories, `relplot` is not the right tool. Either provide the x data in the correct order, or use `catplot`, which has an `order` parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `sns.catplot` , pass the desired order as a list of strings to the function and set the `kind='point'`, as follows:

```
sns.catplot(... ,  
            kind='point', 
            order=['Jan', 'Feb' , ...., 'Dec'])
```

Answer (score 1):

You may wanna use `lineplot()` that returns a matplotlib `Axes` object, which is easy to configure. The basic idea here is to plot the numerical order int first and then add labels. Please consider the following example that uses a sample dataset from seaborn.

```
import calendar
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# sample dataset
df = sns.load_dataset('flights')

# map month name with numerical order
d = dict((v,k) for k,v in enumerate(calendar.month_name[1:], start=1))
df['month_num'] = df.month.map(d)

# plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 5))
sns.lineplot(x='month_num', y='passengers', data=df, hue='year', ax=ax)
# set xticks position and labels
ax.set_xticks(range(1, len(d)+1))
ax.set_xticklabels(d.keys(), rotation=30)
```

[image]